# How to search for a file in all directories using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite a newbie when it comes to Python so excuse me if this is a very simple thing.

How do I make a program search for a file through the whole computer and add the directory of the file to a string?

For example, I want to search for example.py even though I don't have any idea where it could be located.

PS: I'm using Python 3.6.2 in case you need to know that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you tried and where are you failing? You may want to look at [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk).

Comment: `os.walk('/')`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I haven't really tried anything considering I barely know how to use Python. I've seen `os.walk` used in some examples but I can't really understand how to use it.

Comment: @Mike I've marked your answer a duplicate of an existing problem that should fit your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: or from the `cli` do `grep -r "your_text_here"` although be warned it can be slow

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, I'll look into it.